# C++ debugging - error with my code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to write a program to find the number of occurances of each alphabet in a text file. Im encountering some errors which I cant seem to understand.

**Here is the code**
Note: Here i have replaced <> angular brackets with double quotes for headers without the .h extension, bcoz they disappear in the preview box.

//Program to print the number of occurances of each alphabet in a text file

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "string"
#include "genlib.h"

using namespace std; 


void CountLetters(string filename)
{
    Vector<int> count;
    int alphabetSize = 26,i,j;
    ifstream in;
    string line;

    //initialize the vector values. 
    for(i=0;i<alphabetSize;i++)
    {
        count.add(0);
    }
    //opening file
    in.open(filename.c_str()); 
    if(in.fail())
        Error("Error opening file");

    //going thru characters
    while(true)
    {
        getline(in,line);
        if(in.fail())
            break;
        line = ConvertToLowerCase(line);

        for(j=0;j<line.length();j++)
        {
            int index = line[j] - 'a';
            if(index>=0 && index<alphabetSize)
            {
                int previousTotal = count.getAt(index);
                count.setAt(index,previousTotal+1);
            }
        }
    }

    //print values
    for(i=0;i<alphabetSize;i++)
    {
        char ch = 'a' + i;
        cout<<ch<<":"<<count.getAt(i)<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    CountLetters("name.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

**here are the errors:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: section2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  section.cpp
1>section.cpp(35): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

1>section.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl ConvertToLowerCase(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?ConvertToLowerCase@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl CountLetters(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?CountLetters@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

1>section.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Error(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?Error@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl CountLetters(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?CountLetters@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

1>section.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl IntegerToString(int)" (?IntegerToString@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall Vector<int>::checkRange(int,char const *)" (?checkRange@?$Vector@H@@AAEXHPBD@Z)
```

Im using visual c++ 2010 express edition

Comment: So, how do you expect us to help you if you don't show us any code?

Comment: please add code as well... else just try it with adding exception.

Comment: well im sorry abt tat part. but the code dint fit in properly in the first post. i was jus pasting it in the second post now.

Answer (score 2):

The errors you are getting is because you didn't provide implementations for some of the functions you have called. You call a function `Error`, but the linker is saying that it can't find any implementation for such a function. The same is true for `ConvertToLowerCase` and `IntegerToString`. If these functions were declared by genlib.h, then you likely must link to a static or dynamic library to get the implementations, or add a .cpp file defining them to your project.

Comment: well i got those headers from stanford cs106b. So there is file called CS106CPPLib.lib. i placed it in the lib folder in vc++. but i dont see any changes and when i added the lib in the project properties(linker->input) the number of errors increased even more.

Comment: @Jay: You need to ask the author of the library what to do. I can't debug some random library remotely.

Comment: well ur right. I ll rather use the native in built functions. In that way i have one less problem to worry :)  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The functions "Error", "ConvertToLowerCase" and "IntegerToString" seem to belong to another library.  You must link with this library in your project settings -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies.

Presumably they are in genlib.lib?

Comment: well i got those headers from stanford cs106b. So there is file called CS106CPPLib.lib. i placed it in the lib folder in vc++. but i dont see any changes and when i added the lib in the project properties(linker->input) the number of errors increased even more.

Comment: Btw i havent used the function IntegerToString(). atleast to my knowledge. where is it conflicting?

Comment: There are some instructions here: http://abloggingattempt.blogspot.com/2010/05/stanford-cs106-lib-and-vs2008-express.html.   I'm sorry I don't have the files handy myself, so I can't try it out here.